# Cannot upload program to Atmega8

Tags: arduino

Hi I try to upload program (on Atmega8) with I created in Arduino using throught Chinese programmator and I have an error 
**avrdude warning cannot set sck period. please check for usbasp firmware update**
In Arduino I set up:

```
Tools->programmer->USBasp
Tools->Board->Arduino NG or older w/Atmega8
```

to upload the hex code I use the command `File->Upload Using Programmer`

Wher I try to upload thtought khazama program everything ok.

Comment: The Arduino "IDE" sucks big time, if you mean it seriously, code in C and program it directly with avrdude.

Comment: Do you get anything other than that warning? And are you using the Baite EvUSBasp?

Comment: I got only this warning, and I use this programmator

[link]http://www.aliexpress.com/snapshot/6007756306.html?orderId=60868137851418

Answer (score 0):

You're getting that warning because the programmer isn't accepting the speed set command from AVRDUDE. This was an option added to later versions of the USBasp firmware to support slow devices (e.g., ones running off a watch crystal).

However, the programmer you're using (according to that description) auto-adjusts its speed to an appropriate value, so there's no need for AVRDUDE to adjust it in the first place.

And in the end, a warning is still just a warning. Unless you see actual *errors* generated by AVRDUDE the program should have been uploaded to the chip properly regardless.

Comment: By the way, How to change micro controller frequency to 1MHz, by default in Arduino set 16MHz  for Atmega8